# Print entire page with graph using CTRL+P

Tags: anychart

I'm trying to print the entire page with graph using CTRL + P, but the graph is always cropped.

I tried to limit the width of the graph using CSS media = "print", but it seems to have no effect on the graph.

print.css

```css
figure{
width: 100% !important;
/* width: 300px !important; //also does not work */
}
```

If I try to change the size of the graph in CSS media = "screen", the graph will immediately shrink / enlarge.

I know there is a function chart.print(); But it only prints the graph. I need to print the entire page, including the graph. I tried it in Chrome 73. Anychart 8.5.1

Comment: Usually, there are no problems with printing the page with charts. Please, can you provide a screenshot of the page and screenshot of the printed page? Just to compare it visually, it will give us many useful details.

Comment: @AnyChartSupport I created a simple page on your playground site. If you want to print a page (CTRL + P), the graph is cropped. Thank you for your help. [link](https://playground.anychart.com/0bMOWpSg/4/iframe)

Comment: Thank you for pointing us this issue. The problem is that Chrome and FF block the JS interactivity and the SVG part is not resized by the library. Only Safari browser handles this situation properly. We will investigate this issue and update you as soon as we get any workaround.